# ReactiveCocoa Enable NSButton based on NSTableView selection state

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reactive-cocoa

I have just started learning Reactive Cocoa. I am writing cocoa application where i want to enable the NSButton only if at least one row is selected in NSTableView.

I am using the following code in awakeFromNib

```
RACSignal *enableSignal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    @strongify(self);
    if ([self.genreListTableView numberOfSelectedRows] > 0) {
        [subscriber sendNext:@YES];
    } else {
        [subscriber sendNext:@NO];
    }
    return nil;
}];

[self.addButton rac_liftSelector:@selector(setEnabled:)
                      withSignals:enableSignal,nil];
```

This code executed fine and made the addButton disabled during the app launch as there was no row selected Initially.

I want to make add Button enabled when ever TableView entry is selected. I don't know how to achieve in reactive way.

I could achieve the required behavior in the following manner.Not sure if this is the correct way to achieve it.

```
     [[self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(tableViewSelectionDidChange:)
                fromProtocol:@protocol(NSTableViewDelegate)] subscribeNext:^(RACTuple *value) {
    NSNotification *notification = value.first;
    if (self.genreListTableView == notification.object) {
        if ([self.genreListTableView numberOfSelectedRows] > 0) {
            [self.addButton setEnabled:TRUE];
        } else {
            [self.addButton setEnabled:FALSE];
        }
    }
}];
```

Any suggestion is appreciated to handle the requirement in reactive way.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the right track. There are a few changes you should make to simplify.

First, use the `RAC()` macro to do simple bindings like this to a property.

```
RAC(self.addButton, enabled) = /* A signal */;
```

This will cause a compilation error because there is no declared property for `enabled` (and the getter is named `isEnabled`, not just `enabled). This can be fixed very simply with a category:

```
@interface NSButton (EnabledProp)

@property (assign, nonatomic, getter = isEnabled, setter = setEnabled:) BOOL enabled;

@end
```

Then, you can construct a signal directly from the table view's `numberOfSelectedRows` using another macro, `RACObserve()`.

```
RAC(self.addButton, enabled) = RACObserve(self.genreListTableView, numberOfSelectedRows);
```

But that needs to be a `BOOL` for it to make sense as a binding. Transforming one type of value into another? That's a `map:`.

```
RAC(self.addButton, enabled) = [RACObserve(self.genreListTableView, numberOfSelectedRows) map:^id (NSNumber * numSelected){
                                          return @([numSelected integerValue] > 0);
}];
```

The `NSInteger` from `numberOfSelectedRows` is wrapped up in an `NSNumber` when it's in the signal, so unwrap it, compare to zero, and then wrap the comparison result back up.

Comment: I am getting compilation error "No getter method for read from Property" in RAC(self.addButton, enabled). NSButton does not have enabled property like UIButton.

Comment: Updated my answer to address that, @jpsasi.

Comment: compilation issue is resolved now. but now i am having run time AssertFailure with the following error message."Signal <RACReplaySubject: 0x6100002642c0> name: <RACCommand: 0x61000008cee0> -enabled is already bound to key path "enabled" on object <NSButton: 0x6080001446d0>, adding signal <RACDynamicSignal: 0x61000024b940> name: [RACObserve(<NSTableView: 0x100402fa0>, numberOfSelectedRows)] -map: is undefined behavior"

Comment: The `RACCommand` you're using with the button wants to control the button's `enabled` state. There's [a thread on GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/931#issuecomment-28271173) that should help you resolve that.

Comment: Looks like @Dmitry Seredinov approach is simple. But code block is not getting executed whenever i select an entry in table view. do you know what is the issue?

Comment: What code block? If you have another problem, please ask another question.

Comment: This sort of thing can be done with `RACCommand` directly. There shouldn't be any need to circumvent it to manually update the button's `enabled` state. In fact, doing so will probably result in nondeterministic updates, like that assertion is trying to point out.

Comment: Ah yes, of course, @JustinSpahr-Summers. Thanks for pointing that out. In my defense, I don't believe there was any sign in the question that an RACCommand was involved. But I should revise my answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah, sorry, you're right that the `RACCommand` wasn't called out. Unfortunately and unrelatedly, I suspect that KVOing this property [won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146002/reactivecocoa-enable-nsbutton-based-on-nstableview-selection-state/21147089?noredirect=1#comment32061859_21156293).

Answer (score 2):

Using Josh Caswell's approach, you can modify the observation as follows:

```
[[[RACObserve(self.genreListTableView, numberOfSelectedRows) distinctUntilChanged] deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]] subscribeNext:^(NSNumber* numSelected) {
    [self.addButton setEnabled:([numSelected integerValue] > 0)];
}];
```

Comment: I have added this code block in awakeFromNib method. this is getting executed only once when app launches. there after code block is NOT getting invoked even though i select an entry in tableview.But tableview delegate method(- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification) is getting invoked every time when i select the tableview. i removed the tableview delegate and tried it, signal is not getting triggered. am i doing anything wrong here?.

Comment: `subscribeNext:` should almost always be avoided if possible. In this case, it's not only possible, it's easy to avoid.\

Comment: @JoshCaswell I do apologize for an offtopic: I'm not so advanced user of ReactiveCocoa, but please let me ask a question: why we should avoid (almost always) using of `subscribeNext:` selector? Thanks. I hope this will give me some 'best practices' information.

Comment: I don't mind, nor is that off-topic, I think. There's [a brief section on it](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#avoid-explicit-subscriptions-and-disposal) in one of the RAC design documents. The gist is, if the goal is to write less imperative code and more functional code, `subscribeNext:` doesn't get you very far towards that goal. You end up with a Block filled with imperative code rather than a descriptive signal chain.

Comment: AppKit and UIKit properties (like `numberOfSelectedRows`) are generally not observable unless documented as such. `RACObserve` is just a nice wrapper for plain ol' KVO, so many of the same caveats apply.